# Как работает switch в Java

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю откуда появилось 6, я думал что будет 2 , потому и завалил собеседования. Интересно почему там 6, а не 2?

Comment: потому что нету `break;`

Comment: Чтобы не получать минусы, старайтесь формулировать вопрос лучше и **не** приводить код в виде скриншота.

Comment: Я вот, честно говоря, тоже всегда недоумеваю почему оно в подобных случаях проваливается в `case 1:`, когда `s` уже равно `2`. Было бы понятнее если бы оператор `swich` заменили на какой-нибудь `goto` - переход к метке и дальнейшее выполнение кода после метки. По сути, ведь так оно и есть.

Answer (score 6):

Ваши рассуждения забывют о том, что там нет `break`, а в этом случае `case` "проваливается". То есть, грубо говоря, компилятор видит этот код по другому, где то так

```
i = 0;
s = 0;
s+=2; i+=s;
s+=2; i+=s;
```

Правильным ответом на подобный вопрос будет - здесь нет `break`, это плохой код.

Comment: Если нет `break` еще не значит, что код плохой) Есть ситуации когда его специально опускают, чтоб проваливался дальше

Comment: да, есть трюки, когда его опускают. И один из таких случаев - когда идет несколько case подряд. И это нормально (просто в java6 нет возможности в case писать диапазон). А вот подобный код в примере - это пример плохого кода.

Comment: @KoVadim правильным ответом будет "6", а не "это плохой код" :-)

Comment: мне задавали подобный вопрос на собеседовании. Я спросил - а у Вас весь код так пишут? Дальше было весело.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что после первого `case` нет оператора `break` (или другого оператора прерывания), соответственно выполнение программы переходит к следующему `case`.